# Merge two dictionaries and keep the values for duplicate keys in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

Let's suppose that I have two dictionaries:

```
dic1 =  { "first":1, "second":4, "third":8} 
dic2 =  { "first":9, "second":5, "fourth":3}
```

Is there a straightforward way to obtain something like the below?

```
dic3 =  { "first":[1,9], "second":[4,5], "third":[8], "fourth":[3]}
```

I used lists to store values, but tuples are fine as well.

Comment: Are you sure you want the items that appear in only one dictionary to be bare items, rather than lists of one item?

Comment: @interfect Ok, I see your point, I am making an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I would say it's bad practice to cast the values of different keys as different object types. I would simply do something like:

```
def merge_values(val1, val2):
    if val1 is None:
        return [val2]
    elif val2 is None:
        return [val1]
    else:
        return [val1, val2]
dict3 = {
    key: merge_values(dic1.get(key), dic2.get(key))
    for key in set(dic1).union(dic2)
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'll edit already to stick with the same type everywhere.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to hold lists, and then just append the values to them.  This approach easily extends to an arbitrary number of dictionaries.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)

dics = [dic1, dic2]
for dic in dics:
    for key, val in dic.iteritems():  # .items() in Python 3.
        dd[key].append(val)

>>> dict(dd)
{'first': [1, 9], 'fourth': [3], 'second': [4, 5], 'third': [8]}
```

All of the keys with a single value are still held within a list, which is probably the best way to go.  You could, however, change anything of length one into the actual value, e.g.

```
for key, val in dd.iteritems():  # .items() in Python 3.
    if len(val) == 1
        dd[key] = val[0]
```

Comment: This implementation will have all values in the resulting `defaultdict` be of type `list` even if there is no duplicate value within the key. If the preferred behavior is to leave single values as that values' type, then we should check for the existence of a key before adding and convert to a list only when that key already existed.

Comment: @ctj232 OP corrected question to have them in a list structure, which makes more sense anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a naive solution; copy one of the dictionaries over to the result and iterate over the other dictionary's keys and values, adding lists to the result as necessary. Since there are only two dictionaries, no merged list will have more than 2 items.

```
dic1 = {"first": 1, "second": 4, "third": 8} 
dic2 = {"first": 9, "second": 5, "fourth": 3}
dic3 = dict(dic2)

for k, v in dic1.items():
    dic3[k] = [dic3[k], v] if k in dic3 else v

print(dic3) # => {'first': [9, 1], 'second': [5, 4], 'fourth': 3, 'third': 8}
```

If you'd like single values to be lists (likely better design; mixed types aren't much fun to deal with) you can use:

```
dic3 = {k: [v] for k, v in dic2.items()}

for k, v in dic1.items():
    dic3[k] = dic3[k] + [v] if k in dic3 else [v]

print(dic3) # => {'first': [9, 1], 'second': [5, 4], 'fourth': [3], 'third': [8]}
```

---

Generalizing it to any number of dictionaries:

```
def merge_dicts(*dicts):
    """
    >>> merge_dicts({"a": 2}, {"b": 4, "a": 3}, {"a": 1})
    {'a': [2, 3, 1], 'b': [4]}
    """
    merged = {}
    
    for d in dicts:
        for k, v in d.items():
            if k not in merged:
                merged[k] = []

            merged[k].append(v)
    
    return merged
```

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to clean it up a bit if you don't mind the import:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def merge_dicts(*dicts):
    """
    >>> merge_dicts({"a": 2}, {"b": 4, "a": 3}, {"a": 1})
    defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [2, 3, 1], 'b': [4]})
    """
    merged = defaultdict(list)
    
    for d in dicts:
        for k, v in d.items():
            merged[k].append(v)
    
    return merged
```

Comment: If OP wants single element lists, one could use [*set([dic3[k], v])] instead of the ternary if expression.

Answer (score 3):

Given:

```
dic1 =  { "first":1, "second":4, "third":8} 
dic2 =  { "first":9, "second":5, "fourth":3}
```

You can use `.setdefault`:

```
dic_new={}
for k,v in list(dic1.items())+list(dic2.items()):
    dic_new.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
else:
    dic_new={k:v if len(v)>1 else v[0] for k,v in dic_new.items()}  

>>> dic_new
{'first': [1, 9], 'second': [4, 5], 'third': 8, 'fourth': 3}
```

This produces the output in question. I think that flattening the single elements lists to a different object type is an unnecessary complexity.

---

With the edit, this produces the desired result:

```
dic_new={}
for k,v in list(dic1.items())+list(dic2.items()):
    dic_new.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

>>> dic_new
{'first': [1, 9], 'second': [4, 5], 'third': [8], 'fourth': [3]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using set and dictionary comprehension

```
L = [d1, d2]
dups = set(d1.keys() & d2.keys())
d = {k: [L[0][k], L[1][k]] if k in dups else i[k] for i in L for k in i}
```

> ```
> {'first': [1, 9], 'second': [4, 5], 'third': 8, 'fourth': 3}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new dictionary `dic` having for keys the keys of `dic1` and `dic2` and value an empty list, then iterate over `dic1` and `dic2` appending values to `dic`:

```
dic1 =  { "first":1, "second":4, "third":8} 
dic2 =  { "first":9, "second":5, "fourth":3}

dic = {key:[] for key in list(dic1.keys()) + list(dic2.keys())}

for key in dic1.keys():
    dic[key].append(dic1[key])

for key in dic2.keys():
    dic[key].append(dic2[key])
```

Comment: Python 2 only as written. Python 3 would give a `TypeError` here with `dic1.keys() + dic2.keys()`

Comment: Converting dict.keys() to list gives compatibility with python3.
I never searched why base functions like `sum` don't work anymore on arbitrary types in python3.
`sum` over lists of strings was very convenient.

Comment: Now maybe make it a bit more efficient with `dic = {key:[] for key in {k for k in list(dic1) + list(dic2)}}` so that duplicate keys are eliminated.

Comment: Set conversion would still read the whole list to create the set. I didn't convert it because it would weigh down the notation even more and one would not gain anything on memory front.

Comment: Python is just trying to protect you. Using `sum` to concatenate a list of strings would be a classic example of a [Shlemiel the painter](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/) algorithm. Concatenating n strings would create n-2 temporary strings.

Comment: Protecting me from aliasing sum of strings to `''.join`?

Sorry but I couldn't understand how the link relates to `sum`. The redundant calculations are described in the article as dependant on `+` implementation; so if it is the case for python, any concatenation of n strings that uses `+` is an efficient `join`. So why just not alias `+` between strings to a binary `''.join` `sum` of strings to normal `''.join` instead of keeping an inefficient string concatenator?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for dict of lists (adapted from @dawg):

```
dic1 =  { "first":[1], "second":[4], "third":[8]} 
dic2 =  { "first":[9], "second":[5], "fourth":[3]}
dic_new={}
for k,v in list(dic1.items())+list(dic2.items()):
    dic_new.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
>>> dic_new
{'first': [1, 9], 'second': [4, 5], 'third': [8], 'fourth': [3]}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from copy import deepcopy


def _add_value_to_list(value, lis):
    if value:
        if isinstance(value, list):
            lis.extend(value)
        else:
            lis.append(value)
    else:
        pass


def _merge_value(value_a, value_b):
    merged_value = []
    _add_value_to_list(value_a, merged_value)
    _add_value_to_list(value_b, merged_value)
    return merged_value


def _recursion_merge_dict(new_dic, dic_a, dic_b):
    if not dic_a or not dic_b:
        return new_dic
    else:
        if isinstance(new_dic, dict):
            for k, v in new_dic.items():
                new_dic[k] = _recursion_merge_dict(v, dic_a.get(k, {}), dic_b.get(k, {}))
            return new_dic
        else:
            return _merge_value(dic_a, dic_b)


def merge_dicts(dic_a, dic_b):
    new_dic = deepcopy(dic_a)
    new_dic.update(dic_b)

    return _recursion_merge_dict(new_dic, dic_a, dic_b)
```